# In Eiffel, what is the difference between entities, variables, fields and arguments?

Tags: eiffel, language-concepts

I've seen the terms **entity**, **variable**, and **argument** used to describe things about Eiffel, that look quite similar to me, and I wanted to understand what is the *intention* behind using either term instead of the other.

**Arguments** — Some routines require some data in order to run. Imagine a fictitious feature `foo (x, y: INTEGER; z: BOOLEAN)`. This routine takes 3 arguments: `x`, `y`, and `z`. When you call the routine, you must give it three valid arguments, for instance `foo(6, 92, False)`. These values we passed to the routine are called **actual arguments**, while the placeholders defined in the definition are called **formal arguments**.

I've read of **object fields**, which specify the place inside the object structure where values are stored (either references or expanded objects).

I think the only time I saw the term **variables** was for *local variables*, inside features.

And **entity** seems to be a generic term for denoting a data-container with a name, so *local variables*, *arguments*, and *querys* (features that return some data) are all examples of *entities*.

And in what category would `Current` and `Result` fall? **Local variables**?

Could someone help me with the terminology?

Comment: I'll mark @Alexander Kogtenkov's answer as accepted. That answer shows in detail how the terminology is defined by the language specification. I found it *very* clear, and easy to follow. `@Emmanuel Stapf's answer feels more like a wrap-up, complementing the other answer. Reading it right afterwards feels nice, but is not essential for understanding the terminology.

Comment: @Emmanuel Stapf, see the previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Specification

According to ISO/IEC 25436:2006(E) and newly added language constructs:

### Syntax-based terms

**Local variable** is any of the following:

- an identifier declared in a *Local_declarations* part (of a feature body, including inline agents)
- predefined entity `Result`

**Formal argument**:

- an identifier to represent information passed by callers

**Actual argument**:

- an expression in a particular call to the routine

**Variable attribute** is a feature declaration satisfying all of the following:

- there are no formal arguments
- there is a query mark (i.e. it has a type)
- there is no explicit value (i.e. it is not a constant)
- if there is a body, it is of *Attribute* kind

**Constant attribute** is a feature declaration satisfying all of the following:

- there are no formal arguments
- there is a query mark (i.e. it has a type)
- there is an explicit value

### Collective terms

**Variable** is any of the following:

- a final name of a **variable attribute**
- **local variable** (including `Result`)

**Read-only entity** is any of the following:

- **formal argument**
- **object test local**
- **cursor local** (in *Iteration_part* of a loop)
- **separate local** (in *Separate_instruction*)
- **constant attribute**
- `Current`

**Entity** is any of the following:

- **variable**
- **read-only entity**

**Query** is any of the following:

- **attribute**
- **function**

I.e. a query is a feature that has a type and can be used to get a value at run-time.

### Semantics terms

**Field**:

- a value in a direct instance of a non-basic type, corresponding to an **attribute**

---

## Example

```
class C feature
   pi: REAL_32 = 3.14
   double (x: LIST [INTEGER]): LIST [INTEGER]
      local
         r: ARRAYED_LIST [INTEGER]
      do
         create r.make (x.count)
         across x as c loop
            r.extend (c.item * 2)
         end
         Result := r
      end
   average_age: NATURAL
   count: NATURAL
   print_list (x: LIST [PERSON])
      do
         average_age := 0
         count := 0
         x.do_all (agent (p: PERSON)
            do
               if attached p.name as n then
                  io.put_string (n + ": " + p.age.out + "%N")
                  average_age := average_age + p.age
                  count := count + 1
               end
            end)
          if count > 0 then
             average_age := average_age // count
          end
      end
end
```

### Syntax-based terms

Local variable: `r`, `Result`.

Object test local: `n`.

Cursor local: `c`.

Formal argument: `x`, `p`.

Actual argument: `x.count`, `2` (this is an argument for multiplication), `c.item * 2`, `": "` (in string concatenation), `p.age.out`, `"%N"`, `n + ": " + p.age.out + "%N"`, `p.age`, `1`, `0`, `count` (in division).

Variable attribute: `average_age`, `count`.

Constant attribute: `pi`.

### Collective terms

Variable: `r`, `Result`, `average_age`, `count`.

Read-only entity: `pi`, `n`, `c`, `x`, `p`.

Entity: `pi`, `r`, `Result`, `average_age`, `count`, `n`, `c`, `x`, `p`.

Query: `pi`, `double`, `average_age`, `count`.

Comment: Did you forget to include **constant attributes** under **read-only entities**? — I presume that *ISO/IEC 25436:2006(E)* and *ECMA-367 (2nd Edition / June 2006)* have very little difference in content, if any. If section  *"8.19.7 Definition: Entity, variable, read-only"* is equal in both documents, then *"Constant attributes [...] are **read-only**
entities."* (sic for **bold**).

Comment: @g4v3, yes, thank you for the catch. The text is fixed now, including the example.

Answer (score 1):

You will see clear definitions for those terms in the [ECMA Eiffel specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-367.htm) (Standard ECMA-367, section 8: *Language specification*).

To summarize:

An **entity** is either: argument, local, attribute (including constant attribute), *Current* or *Result*.

A **variable** is a local or an attribute (not including constant attribute). However, we often count *Result* as if it was a pseudo locals so it would be ok to call it also a variable, but the standard doesn't.

Note that none of the above includes routines (i.e. procedures or functions, also known as commands and queries in the Eiffel terminology).

Comment: In *ECMA-367 (2nd Edition / June 2006)*, in section *"8.8.9 Definition: Local variable"*, it says that *"The local variables of a routine include [...], if it is a query, the predefined entity **Result**."* See also the *Informative text* that follows, for more details. Would you please update your answer?